# Connecting Azure Linux VM having Ubuntu installed from powershell throwing Host Verification failed. . . error

Tags: linux, azure, powershell, ssh, azure-virtual-machine

I tried to connect to Azure Linux VM where Ubuntu installed from https://shell.azure.com/bash

```
ssh username@ipaddress
```

above command is throwing error as `Permission Denied (publickey)` .

[image]

I have created `SSH public key` and added it to VM while creating Azure Linux VM following below article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/quick-create-portal

But still facing `Permission Denied` issue.

Also, I tried to run `bolt command` on Azure Linux VM remotely from another windows machine powershell.

I got error as below

> Host key verification failed for '10.20.30.40':fingerprint
>   SHA256:mssgkeghbfnb9883yygebwndjhk is unknown for '10.20.30.40'

[image]

How to fix above issues. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Ther is normally a step where you can add an SSH public key during setup of the machine. Which SSH key did you add there in that case?

Comment: I have updated in question. I have already created SSH public key and added it to Azure Linux VM while creating it following article mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Permission denied (publickey)` means that your public key is not in the *authorized_keys* file. Copy the public key manually to that user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, or use `ssh-copy-id` which comes with *OpenSSH*.
Also, make sure you're SSH'ing to the right user with `ssh user@host`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Issue fixed after copying public key to authorized keys.